# Center align a display:table-cell inside a td

Tags: html, css

I'm creating an email template - using tables of course.

I have a rounded `p` element inside a `td` , in order to vertical align it's content I used the `display: table-cell` property.

The problem is that now the circle in not center aligned in the `td` any more even when using `margin: 0 auto`

see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gwmqrv8w/)

html:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="circle">
      <p><b>12</b><br/>views</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
td {
   width: 140px;
}

table td.circle p {
   margin: 0 auto;
   height: 70px;
   width: 70px;
   background-color: rgb(92, 177, 251);
   border-radius: 50%;
   text-align: center;
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

How can I center align the circle, without using extra positioning hacks that won't be supported in an email?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need one more element inside `td` becaue you can't use `margin: 0 auto` with `table-cell`. Working code is in below snippet:

```css
td {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 140px;
}

table td.circle div {
  background-color: rgb(92, 177, 251);
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
}

table td.circle p {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
 }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="circle">
      <div>
        <p>
          <b>12</b>
          <br/>
          views
        </p>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `align=center` in td to center the inner element, here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/gwmqrv8w/1/)

Comment: `align` attribute is not supported in HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

```
Do you need likee this


  you can see the link: https://jsfiddle.net/gwmqrv8w/2/


Html code here
<table>
<tr>
  <td align="center" class="circle">
    <p>
    <b>12</b>
    <br/>
    views
    </p>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>

Css code here:
td {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 140px;
}

table td.circle p 
{
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  background-color: rgb(92, 177, 251);
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
   display: table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
table td.circle p {
margin: 0 auto;
height: 70px;
width: 70px;
background-color: rgb(92, 177, 251);
border-radius: 50%;
color: white;
font-size: 14px;
text-align: center;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
position: relative;
left: 31px;
}
```

Add the css  in that class - table td.circle p {position: relative;  left: 31px; }

Answer (score 0):

If you rework you HTML slightly, you can use a combination of flexbox and table-cell:

```
.wrapper{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.digit{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.text{
    display: inline;
}
```

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="number">
        <div class="digit">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec id justo posuere ex pharetra euismod bibendum vel nunc. Donec pharetra ipsum sit amet augue ornare, non sodales leo dapibus. Nunc mollis sodales diam, accumsan
        suscipit justo dignissim vitae. Nunc ultrices a elit nec hendrerit. Cras tempor elit quis nulla scelerisque aliquet. Nulla efficitur ac purus vitae porttitor. Morbi commodo efficitur ornare. Curabitur a ipsum dapibus erat iaculis finibus. Nullam dui nulla,
        viverra id laoreet eget, fringilla ac orci. Nulla iaculis enim vitae dui congue accumsan. Fusce cursus justo non quam sodales blandit
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

vertical-align in table-cell is by default "middle"
So, no need to add this property. Anyhow if you want text horizontally align center you should try following property in your HTML code it will work without using extra positioning:

```
<td align="center">something</td>
```